# Iterate over cells with incrementing ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fill a table with values using Javascript/Jquery.
I have a table with incrementing ids (`td-1`until `td-42`) and I want to fill this table using JQuery/Javascript.
Currently I am using this script, but I know the error `$('#td-'+i)` can't work, because the ID used is build wrong: `$('#td-'12)` is not a valid id.
Has someone a quick fix for this? I am stuck...

```
for (var i = 1; i < 43; i++) {
    if (i < firstDay || i >= (howMany + firstDay)) {
        $('#td-'+i).value("");
    } else {
        $('#td-'+i).value(i-firstDay);
   }
}
```

Comment: why didn't you use this? `$('#td-'+i).text("");` Input elements only has the `.val()` function.. That too not `.value()`

Comment: Good point. You are right of course. But that's not the solution...

Comment: What makes you think jQuery has a `value` function? There's none in [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It has `val`, and it has `text`, and it has `html`, but no `value`.

Comment: *"but I know the error $('#td-'+i) can't work, because the ID used is build wrong: $('#td-'12)"* Not with the code above. With the code above, if `id` is (say) `42`, the resulting selector is `#td-42`, which matches what you said you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text()` and it worked.

```js
var firstDay = 3, howMany = 1;

for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  if (i < firstDay || i >= (howMany + firstDay)) {
    $('#td-'+i).text("");
  } else {
    $('#td-'+i).text(i-firstDay);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='td-1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='td-2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='td-3'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='td-4'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='td-5'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='td-6'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, reconsider putting a large amount of IDs on elements for efficiency reasons, but putting that aside:

There's a convenience callback for `.each()` in jQuery, which accepts incremented (current) index and reference to element.

Depending on the DOM structure, you could do:

```
$('td', '#mytable').each(function(ix, tdel){
   $(tdel).attr('id', 'td-' + ix).text(ix); // or $(this).attr...
});
```

...and see where it takes you to.